# Overflow error in vbscript

Tags: vbscript, excel, vba

I am getting an "Overflow" error on line 40 of the following script:

```
Set objDialog = CreateObject("UserAccounts.CommonDialog")

objDialog.Filter = "Excel|*.xls|All Files|*.*"
objDialog.FilterIndex = 1
objDialog.InitialDir = "D:\"   
intResult = objDialog.ShowOpen 

If intResult = 0 Then
Wscript.Quit
 Else
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objDialog.FileName) 
End If


objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Foaie1") 
objWorksheet2.Activate 


objExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
objExcel.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Set RngVal = objWorksheet2.Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Columns(4)
Set RngCrt = RngVal.Offset(0, -3)

objWorksheet2.Select
objWorksheet2.Range("A2").Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
Criteria = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7).Value = objExcel.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(RngCrt, Criteria, RngVal) / objExcel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngCrt, Criteria)
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7).Value = objExcel.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(RngCrt, Criteria, RngVal) / objExcel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngCrt, Criteria)

objExcel.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
objExcel.ScreenUpdating = True
```

The script calculates the average of column "D", and when the value from "A" changes, puts the result in "H".

Example:

```
 1. "A"         "D"                "H"
 2. 07:36:16    8.4
 3. 07:36:16    3.4                 5.9
 4. 07:36:17    2.1
```

Comment: What Tim said, plus "overflow" generally implies that you are trying to put a value into a variable that can't handle that value. Since you didn't show how your variables are declared, I don't know how we can help.

Comment: If you are running Windows Server 2003 x64 or Windows XP x64 you may be affected by a fault in the C++ Runtime library and can download a hotfix from Microsoft. For further details, refer to Microsoft KB955536 - [VBScript throws a floating-point exception when the C runtime returns a stale floating-point status flag in a Windows Server 2003 environment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955536).

Answer (score 2):

In your code above the line

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7).Value = objExcel.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(RngCrt, Criteria, RngVal) / objExcel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngCrt, Criteria)
```

Is line 41, so I assume that an extra newline has been added to that sample by mistake because I'm quite sure that's the line that fails.

So the easy way to figure out why it fails is to look at the values being calculated, so try changing that line into something like:

```
value1 = objExcel.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(RngCrt, Criteria, RngVal)
value2 = objExcel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngCrt, Criteria)
msgbox value1
msgbox value2
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 7).Value = value1 / value2
```

I assume that the values shown in the messageboxes won't be what you expect and so will hopefully show you where there error is.